# Margin on absolute element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched around but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I essentially have some basic markup

```
<section id="testimonial" class="section">
  <div id="testimonial-container" class="testimonial-carousel white-back">

  </div>
  <div id="imageContainer" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 offset-6">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyj8ojsALtvYLKCCAxYVuTu3oxP4CmmIfNlC__LvYg4MbPIyZq" class="btmImg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now `testimonial-container` is simply a container for a testimonial slider.  It has a `min-height` of 400px.  The actual section has a height of 100vh.

The part I am struggling with is this.  At the bottom of the section I am placing an image.  Because I am giving it an absolute position, a margin-top will not impact the testimonal-container.  I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/26/) to demonstrate.

As you can see, the bottom image is sitting on top of the testimonial-container.  Is there any way to give it a margin or something to stop this from happening?

Thanks

[image: Design]

So there is a section above this section which I did not include in the Fiddle.  I am working on Section B, which has a min-height of 100vh.  The white area is the testimonial-container, it slightly overlaps Section A, has a width of 400px, and sits in the middle.  There is then an image located at the very bottom of the section.

Comment: absolute element won't see each others, both are off the flow. aside javascript, i do not see what you can do. **But i have a question: Why do you need absolute positionning here ?**

Comment: To be honest, I am open to suggestions.  I just needed to get the testimonial-container at the top, and the image at the very bottom.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you can add a screenshot to explain what you need ?

Comment: Sure, no problem, image has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated the same situation of your image:

```css
.section-A {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section-B {
  position: relative;
  background: brown;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px; /* if you remove min-height <img> will overlap .testimonal-container */
} .testimonial-container {
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%; /* increase to move up */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
} img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="section-A">
</div>

<div class="section-B">
  <div class="testimonial-container">
  </div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyj8ojsALtvYLKCCAxYVuTu3oxP4CmmIfNlC__LvYg4MbPIyZq" />
</div>
```

Same code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/28/

Note that `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` properties are used to horizontal centering the element, because you can't use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on elements that has `position: absolute;`